# Primefaces menu with EL as class StyleClass

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, menu

I'm trying to make a dynamic navigation menu in which one item of current selection should be marked. I'm trying to do it with setting styleClass of the menu item. The menu should be dynamic because of item names stored in the database.

The problem is that EL for style is not calculated and I see it fully in the browser but not only proper style

```
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(name);
    item.setId(id);
    item.setCommand("#{categories.actionSelectCategory}");
    item.setParam(CATEGORY_ID, id);
    item.setStyleClass("#{\"" + id + "\".equals(categories.category) ? \"ui-state-active\" : \"\"}");
```

Here is that I see in browser

```
<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all #{&quot;1&quot;.equals(categories.category) ? &quot;ui-state-active&quot; : &quot;&quot;}">
```

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to use EL in the DefaultMenuItem StyleClass like that as its expecting a String not an EL expression.  Try something simpler than what you are doing like `#{true ? 'true-style' : 'false-style'}` using single quotes just to see if you can get it to evaluate.  If it does not then it might be an issue with PF not allowing EL in the default menu item.  You could submit an enhancement request at: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is very likely that they are not supported but interesting to read about that somethere in documentation. And cool idea with creating an issue.

Comment: I create an issue and they mark it as a new feature.

Comment: Yep because technically its not a bug.  It was never implemented to be used that way so they marked it an enhancement to existing functionality.